# How to add/remove 3d box to Python Mayavi animation visualization?

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

Here is an minimal code to visualize 3d box animation using `mayavi` and `tvtk`.

At time `t==20`, I tried to add a new green box.
However, the `visual.box` automatically run `reset_zoom` inside, and suddenly camera's viewpoint is changed.

How can I add/remove boxes at any time, without affecting the camera?
Is there a better way than using `tvtk`?

```
from mayavi import mlab
from tvtk.tools import visual

fig = mlab.figure(size=(500,500))
visual.set_viewer(fig)

b1 = visual.box()
b2 = visual.box(x=4)
b3 = visual.box(x=-4)
b1.v = 5.0

mlab.view(azimuth=45, elevation=70, focalpoint=[0, 0, 0], distance=62.0, figure=fig)

@mlab.show
@mlab.animate(delay=100)
def anim():
    for i in range(30):
        b1.x = b1.x + b1.v*0.1
        if b1.x > 2.5 or b1.x < -2.5:
            b1.v = -b1.v

        if i==20: 
            """ HERE adding a box automatically reset zooming """
            newbox = visual.box(x=2, y=2, z=2, color=(0,1,0))
        yield

anim()
```

[image: sudden view angle change]

Comment: Could this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29632326/7919597

Comment: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html#accelerating-a-mayavi-script